# Prevent logging of File not found exceptions

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

Hi am getting a lot of errors in the coldfusion exception log from bots trying to access files that no longer exists. Below an example:

```
"Error","ajp-nio-****","12/08/21","11:21:21","****","File not found: **** The specific sequence of files included or processed is: ****'' "
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateNotFoundException: File not found: ***
```

Is there a way to prevent coldfusion from logging TemplateNotFoundException's in it's exceptions logs?

Comment: I suspect that you can't but here is a way to not have to look at them.  https://www.asanet.org/sites/default/files/savvy/CFIDE/administrator/help/filter.htm